# Tikz: Center neurons vertically

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a fully connected neural network with Tikz and would like to know if there is a simple way to center all neuron vertically? If possible, I would like to use my approach. Here is my code and an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\def\layersep{2cm}
\def\hsep{1cm}
\def\ilsize{4}
\def\hlsize{8}
\def\olsize{6}
\def\rootlrp{6}
\def\neuronsize{4mm}

\tikzset{>=latex}

\begin{figure}
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=0pt, ->, draw=black!100, node distance=\layersep]
\tikzstyle{every pin edge}=[<-,shorten <=1pt]
\tikzstyle{neuron}=[circle, draw, fill=black!100, minimum size=\neuronsize,inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{input neuron}=[neuron, fill=black!0]
\tikzstyle{hidden neuron}=[neuron, fill=black!0]
\tikzstyle{output neuron}=[neuron, fill=black!0]

%%%%%%%%%%%%
% DRAW NODES
%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Draw the input layer nodes
\foreach \name / \y in {1,...,\ilsize}
    \node[input neuron] (In-\name) at (0.0cm+\hsep,-\y cm) {};
% Draw the hidden layer nodes
\foreach \name / \y in {1,...,\hlsize}
    \node[hidden neuron] (H0-\name) at (1.5cm+\hsep,-\y cm) {};
% Draw the hidden layer nodes
\foreach \name / \y in {1,...,\hlsize}
    \node[hidden neuron] (H1-\name) at (3.0cm+\hsep,-\y cm) {};
% Draw the output layer nodes
\foreach \name / \y in {1,...,\olsize}
    \node[hidden neuron] (Out-\name) at (4.5cm+\hsep,-\y cm) {};

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% DRAW CONNECTIONS
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Connect every node in the input layer with every node in the hidden layer.
\foreach \source in {1,...,\ilsize}
    \foreach \dest in {1,...,\hlsize}
        \path (In-\source) edge (H0-\dest);
% Connect first with second hidden layer
\foreach \source in {1,...,\hlsize}
    \foreach \dest in {1,...,\hlsize}
        \path (H0-\source) edge (H1-\dest);
% Connect every node from the last hidden layer with the output layer
\foreach \source in {1,...,\hlsize}
    \foreach \dest in {1,...,\olsize}
        \path (H1-\source) edge (Out-\dest);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another version of [ABlueChampions answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/540291/194703), which I just see now,  which leaves your plot intact but I really could not leave the `\tikzstyle`s in.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
% really bad practice, sorry
\def\layersep{2cm}
\def\hsep{1cm}
\def\ilsize{4}
\def\hlsize{8}
\def\olsize{6}
\def\rootlrp{6}
\def\neuronsize{4mm}

\tikzset{>=latex}

\begin{figure}
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=0pt, ->, draw=black!100, node distance=\layersep,
     every pin edge/.style={<-,shorten <=1pt},
     neuron/.style={circle, draw, fill=black!100, minimum size=\neuronsize,inner sep=0pt},
     input neuron/.style={neuron, fill=black!0},
     hidden neuron/.style={neuron, fill=black!0},
     output neuron/.style={neuron, fill=black!0}]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\iyshift}{0.5*\ilsize-0.5*\hlsize}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\oyshift}{0.5*\olsize-0.5*\hlsize}
%%%%%%%%%%%%
% DRAW NODES
%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Draw the input layer nodes
\foreach \name / \y in {1,...,\ilsize}
    \node[input neuron] (In-\name) at (0.0cm+\hsep,-\y cm+\iyshift cm) {};
% Draw the hidden layer nodes
\foreach \name / \y in {1,...,\hlsize}
    \node[hidden neuron] (H0-\name) at (1.5cm+\hsep,-\y cm) {};
% Draw the hidden layer nodes
\foreach \name / \y in {1,...,\hlsize}
    \node[hidden neuron] (H1-\name) at (3.0cm+\hsep,-\y cm) {};
% Draw the output layer nodes
\foreach \name / \y in {1,...,\olsize}
    \node[hidden neuron] (Out-\name) at (4.5cm+\hsep,-\y cm+\oyshift cm) {};

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% DRAW CONNECTIONS
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Connect every node in the input layer with every node in the hidden layer.
\foreach \source in {1,...,\ilsize}
    \foreach \dest in {1,...,\hlsize}
        \path (In-\source) edge (H0-\dest);
% Connect first with second hidden layer
\foreach \source in {1,...,\hlsize}
    \foreach \dest in {1,...,\hlsize}
        \path (H0-\source) edge (H1-\dest);
% Connect every node from the last hidden layer with the output layer
\foreach \source in {1,...,\hlsize}
    \foreach \dest in {1,...,\olsize}
        \path (H1-\source) edge (Out-\dest);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I saw your comment `% really bad practice, sorry`. Thank you for the feedback! How can I do it better?

Comment: Ti*k*Z has the possibility to store everything in pgf keys. That way you do not need these `\def`s. In your document, these `\def`s are bad in two ways. (i) Unlike `\newcommand`, they just overwrite macro's without asking. Imagine you share this with a collaborator, and each of you add wildly `\def`s. Chances are that you overwrite your collaborator's macros, and even worse you may lose some long time to find the source of the problem. (ii) You do the `\def`s at the document level. If you were to do them in side the `tikzpicture`, they will be less harmful.

Answer (score 2):

You could always resort back to good old math and add `- 0.5*\hlsize cm + 0.5*\ilsize cm` to the *y*-coordinates of the input and output nodes (this should work somewhat generally, if I haven't made some embarrassing mistake). I hope that's what you meant / wanted:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\def\layersep{2cm}
\def\hsep{1cm}
\def\ilsize{4}
\def\hlsize{8}
\def\olsize{6}
\def\rootlrp{6}
\def\neuronsize{4mm}

\tikzset{>=latex}

\begin{figure}
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=0pt, ->, draw=black!100, node distance=\layersep]
\tikzstyle{every pin edge}=[<-,shorten <=1pt]
\tikzstyle{neuron}=[circle, draw, fill=black!100, minimum size=\neuronsize,inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{input neuron}=[neuron, fill=black!0]
\tikzstyle{hidden neuron}=[neuron, fill=black!0]
\tikzstyle{output neuron}=[neuron, fill=black!0]

%%%%%%%%%%%%
% DRAW NODES
%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Draw the input layer nodes
\foreach \name / \y in {1,...,\ilsize}
    \node[input neuron] (In-\name) at (0.0cm+\hsep,-\y cm - 0.5*\hlsize cm + 0.5*\ilsize cm) {};
% Draw the hidden layer nodes
\foreach \name / \y in {1,...,\hlsize}
    \node[hidden neuron] (H0-\name) at (1.5cm+\hsep,-\y cm) {};
% Draw the hidden layer nodes
\foreach \name / \y in {1,...,\hlsize}
    \node[hidden neuron] (H1-\name) at (3.0cm+\hsep,-\y cm) {};
% Draw the output layer nodes
\foreach \name / \y in {1,...,\olsize}
    \node[hidden neuron] (Out-\name) at (4.5cm+\hsep,-\y cm - 0.5*\hlsize cm + 0.5*\olsize cm) {};

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% DRAW CONNECTIONS
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Connect every node in the input layer with every node in the hidden layer.
\foreach \source in {1,...,\ilsize}
    \foreach \dest in {1,...,\hlsize}
        \path (In-\source) edge (H0-\dest);
% Connect first with second hidden layer
\foreach \source in {1,...,\hlsize}
    \foreach \dest in {1,...,\hlsize}
        \path (H0-\source) edge (H1-\dest);
% Connect every node from the last hidden layer with the output layer
\foreach \source in {1,...,\hlsize}
    \foreach \dest in {1,...,\olsize}
        \path (H1-\source) edge (Out-\dest);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]